# How to get the cursor on Editext of child item of the Recyclerview when the new item is added to it?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView where I'm adding the child items to it on click of the button dynamically. Each Child Item has a Editext.
When a new child item is been added to the RecyclerView the Editetext of the new item should get the focus.
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried  `edittext.requestFocus();` ?

Comment: Where should i put the code exactly. Is it in the Adapter class?

Comment: Where you add the child. After you add it, `requestFocus()`. It should be the first thing after you add it, since you want each child to have focus upon insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request a  focus inside your Adapter.

Something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

((ViewHolder) holder).yourEditText.requestFocus(); // It will set a focus on your edittext whenever the child is getting created

}
```

Comment: I have added the code piece. But the focus is in the last item instead of first item

Comment: If you want a focus only at the first position. you can add a condition on the basis of position.
if(position==0){
((ViewHolder) holder).yourEditText.requestFocus();
}

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is by setting focus to EditText in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int)` method.

Then set focus normally using: `yourEditText.requestFocus();`